# Static table view cells: Clear color not corresponding

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have the below controller with the cell's, content view's, and table view's `backgroundColor` set to `.clear`, however, there is still a white background which I can't figure out what it is corresponding to.

[image]

Comment: Did you set backgroundcolor for uitableviewcell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to debug it in your Xcode. To do this you can launch it on you device(or on simulator), click 'Debug View Hierarchy' button. [image]

Then by Mouse Click + Dragging on the screen rectangle you can rotate all layers of your screen and see which view is causing that white background.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to Your table view cell colour.

Select table view cell:

[image]

Set its background colour as clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this white background is due to table view cell select table view cell and from navigator make its background clear. or you can do it in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

[image: image here]

this will solve your problem... 
:)